# How do I extend my 4 input NAND to get a 5 input NAND

Tags: logic-gates

[image]

This is my NAND with 4 inputs. Only using NAND's how do I extend this to create a 5 input NAND

Comment: Where would the fifth input go? There's also no ultimatum that you have explained here. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Add two more NANDs. Break the line between the output of either 'inverter' and the final NAND. Mark the output of the 'inverter' as R. Mark the hanging input of the final NAND as S. Now construct an AND out of the two new NANDs. Insert this AND gate, so that R goes to one of its inputs and its output goes to S. The other input to the AND is your added E input. It should be obvious to you why this works. If not, and you explain that you really want to understand, I'll write an explanation. You could also just invert your Q output (to make an AND), feed that to a NAND, adding E as input to that.

Comment: Throw it away and buy a 74xx30  or 74xx133...

Comment: @Trevor: some people draw gates on silicon

Comment: @jbord39 I know.. I just could not resist..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJxFJx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: @Tut - Whoops! You're right. For some reason I thought an AND was needed. I've fixed.

Comment: Yeah. That looks better. I'd stated that in my comment at the end.